# $\frac{b_1b_2\cdots b_n}{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\leq\frac{B}{A}$, prove $\frac{(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots (b_n+1)}{(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_n+1)}\leq\frac{B}{A}$

Tags: inequality, induction, products

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $a_i,b_i, A, B\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $a_i\leq b_i, a_i\leq A\ (i=1,2,\cdots, n),$ and $$\dfrac{b_1b_2\cdots b_n}{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\leq\dfrac{B}{A}. $$ Prove that$$\frac{(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots (b_n+1)}{(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_n+1)}\leq\frac{B}{A}$$

I tried to use induction and have proved $n=1$ case, but it seems it has some difficulty to go from $n$ to $n+1$ (my method is to let $a_1a_2, b_1b_2$ be a whole, but to do this we have to assume $a_1a_2\leq A$).

Apprecaite a valid and complete proof!

Comment: Stope please to change the problem and open another topic with your new problem.

Comment: Also, you can  post your new problem without deleting of the first. I think it would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Since $b_i\geq a_i$, we obtain $$\frac{b_i}{a_i}\geq\frac{1+b_i}{1+a_i}$$ and
$$\frac{B}{A}-\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+b_i)}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)}\geq\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n b_i}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_i}-\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+b_i)}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)}\geq0.$$

Comment: Apologize for typing the conclusion wrongly. Would you do it again?

Comment: @user823011 But it's really another problem. It's not faire. Restore please the previous problem and open another topic with your new problem.

Comment: @user823011  All problems in math are similar. Just post your new problem in another topic. By the way, I solved your new problem too. Do it.

Comment: However the system forbids me froming posting the new one due to the similarity, and I cannot delete this one now. :(

Comment: @user823011 OK. Post your new problem without deleting of the first. I think it would be better.

Comment: No, I cannot post the new problem now, because the 2 questions are too similar in words  hence the system forbids me do so. I acknowledge your efforts but I have to edit this post into the correct one. I will add the old problem inito the post and please do not edit again.